# How to inpaint using the stable diffusion webui api?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, stable-diffusion, inpainting

i am asking how to inpaint using the stable diffusion webui api.

I am currently searching for a python source where i select an mask image and an prompt anf the the masked content is beeing filled with the prompt. But how to do this with Stable Diffusion Webui Api

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.